# Capture column values from reordered DataTables.js rows

Tags: jquery-ui, datatables

I want to use DataTables.js to build a table of values as input to a form. I want the user to be able to reorder the rows as they wish, and so I can grab the values of the column in the user's preferred order.

The use case is that I want to build an array of the column values in the order the user has selected, and submit that array as part of a form. The idea is that this array will be used to present a table of results in the user-defined order rather than, say, alphabetical. It doesn't look like there's an easy way to rearrange options in a  list in HTML directly but DataTables makes drag-and-drop ordering of the rows easy.

Suggestions welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Like this? https://datatables.net/extensions/rowreorder/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that's quite what I want. Rearranging rows already works quite well with drag-and-drop. 

The question isn't how I allow the user to rearrange the rows. That works. The question is how do I retrieve the values in the column after the rows have been rearranged? It doesn't look like the extension helps with that.

Comment: I would suggest you provide a more complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Also look at https://datatables.net/reference/api/toArray()

Comment: Ah! toArray() looks like what I was looking for. Thanks so much.